# How to get referral parameters from App Store?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, appsflyer

Is there way to get referrer parameters used to open app's App Store page on its first run? I tried to get these parameters in application(_:open:options:) method of AppDelegate, but this method is not called.

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: @dasdom, but how services like apps flyer can track such parameters?

Comment: In my opinion, they can only track such parameters if they provide links they control. Apple does not provide such parameters for the App Store.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? There are affiliate and campaign parameters for different tracking purposes. With campaign parameters you can do attribution for example.

Comment: @Oddie, I am using AppsFlyer and I want to pass campaign parameters to backend on first app run. That parameters are custom and indicate source of installation, referrer id and some other custom parameters.

Comment: @aleos Then I'd rather go over to them and get guidance. Nothing you can do with the "official" App Store

Comment: Thank you, @Oddie, for your reply. May be deferred deep linking or universal links can help? I do not fully understand how these technologies work. I will very glad to any further help in this issue.